# Where is "Devil's Leap" in The Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

After I stumbled upon a refugee camp and liberated it from filthy deserters I found this poster. It mentions Devil's Leap but I cant find anything about it. Here is a screenshot :
[image]

Comment: I have found in playing the game (ps4), that there are a few posters and bits of information that have little relevance to any side quests or actual locations, such as this one above. I would assume this is for followers of the Eternal Fire. I also seem to remember something about a "Devil's Leap" being mentioned in a conversation between two Eternal Fire witch hunters during the quest in which you unravel the mysteries of the Barons lost wife. (Trying not to give away spoilers).

Comment: There is no named Location called the Devil's Leap in the Witcher 3. I think that might hint at a quest that was never implemented and therefore only a few references to it remain. Could also be a hint at a surprise update with a new quest-line in it (which would be great)

Comment: There's talk of a part of the Devil's Pit area that is thought to be a yet-unfinished part of the game http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:25266 Maybe it's related?

Comment: Of course the game is complete now, so it's probably remnants of something unfinished like @Crowley said.

Answer (score 1):

[Devil's Pit is located east of Mulbrydale and southeast of Hanged Man's Tree.](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Devil's+Pit)

Comment: The question is asking about Devil's Leap, not Devil's Pit.

Comment: @Vemonus - fixed

Answer (score 0):

Is it where the Harpie was near Crookback Bog where you retrieve the voice box for the half-ling the lil blue guy after the crones took it from him? The perch where the harpie's nest was had a similar name I believe.